# Cannot display db table content in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, controllers, model, resource-model

This is my Controller/index.php

```
<?php

namespace Wallet\Payment\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Wallet\Payment\Model\CashbackFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_modelFriendFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param FriendFactory $modelFriendFactory
     */

     public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CashbackFactory $modelFriendFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_modelFriendFactory = $modelFriendFactory;
    }


    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
         $friendModel = $this->_modelFriendFactory->create();
                 $friend = $friendModel->load(1);
        if($friend){
            echo $friend->getName() . " found with Id 1";
            echo "<hr/>";
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Post your error code so people can get idea about your issue.

Comment: I'm just seeing white screen error